# Are there any Ant conventions similar to Maven2 conventions?

Tags: java, ant, automated-tests, conventions

For the past 2 years-(ish) I've been using [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org) for my build/continuous integration solution.  I used [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) a bit before that but really didn't get a lot of experience with it.  Now I've taken a new job and the team I'm on now uses Ant.

What I'm wondering about is this:

In Maven we had directory conventions for seperating our java source and files and java test files ([JUnit](http://junit.org) tests).  It looked like this:

```
Project-
  -src/main/java
  -src/test/java
```

This way your tests are separate from your source/production code and won't be built/deployed as such.

Going over the Ant documentation I don't really see any convention for this. Am I missing something?  Is there a similar convention in Ant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience with ant -- which is our primary build tool for Java source, so make of this what you will -- is that there are no such *formal* conventions.  Many source projects I've seen organize things in a similar manner; JBoss uses <module>/src/main for sources, etc...  Ant just uses whatever conventions you want, which makes it an ideal tool to integrate into a larger project building framework.

At any rate, the Maven conventions work just fine for Ant, so if you've already got them in place, just re-use the same structures.  Not only is it easier for you to keep track of where things are, when you use a familiar structure, but if you ever decide to mavenize the project, you'll already be set.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of ANT conventions/best practices are explained in [ANT in Anger](http://ant.apache.org/ant_in_anger.html)

Answer (score 0):

An older resource but fine in my opinion are [ant-best-practices](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/17/ant_bestpractices.html).